# Sencha touch textfield label stretches to full screen on android app

Tags: android, css, html, sencha-touch-2, cross-platform

I am creating a cross platform app with Sencha touch 2, the UI on iOS works fine, but labels of my textfield and numberfield stretches to full screen even though I have mentioned label width as 30%. Can anyone tell the cause behind this? Input elements on my android app look weird because of this (label in one line and input element in another line)
(EDIT)
Sample code:-

```
{
 xtype: 'textfield',
 id: 'source',
 label: 'Source',
 labelWidth: '30%',
 styleHtmlContent: true,
 name: 'source'
}
```

The textfield is present inside this hierarchy Ext.Container->formpanel->fieldset
I have tried with and without setting styleHtmlContent. It works fine with Cupertino theme but not with MountainView

Comment: Did you try giving it a number? Can you please post some code, I want to make sure in which container its being used.

Comment: Updated question with more details.
Even simple number doesn't work.

Comment: Whats the container? Is it inside the Ext.form.Panel ?

Comment: @UmarKashmiri yes the formpanel mentioned above is Ext.form.Panel which contains fieldset, inside which I have these fields.